# Как сделать, чтобы при раскрытии одного блока, нижестоящие блоки передвинулись вниз?

Tags: jquery, css

[Вот ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Y46/)

Как сделать, чтобы когда первый блок раскрывался, то нижестоящие блоки передвигались. Т.е при раскрытии он передвинул нижние блоки?

Я несколько раз делал такое, каждый раз они сами передвигали. А в этот раз чет не работает. Буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Уберите `height: 100px;` из селектора `#topics`.
2. Не присваивайте одинаковый `id` нескольким элементам. Если нужно применить один стиль к нескольким элементам, используйте `class`.

http://jsfiddle.net/G2Y46/6/

Comment: спасибо. Я везде классы использовал. Исправил тут код, оказалось что не сохранилось. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

У тебя жестко задана высота в 100px, поэтому остальной текст за ее рамками уже является переполнением overflow. Соответственно браузер не выполняем преобразования при этом, исправь в #topics свойство height на min-height:100px.